# "Problem with Audio Playback" on Skype

Tags: skype

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit and from the beginning Skype is not working.

When I press the Video Call button starts a call and shows me a warning that has problem with Audio Playback.

I recently deleted Windows 7 and putted Ubuntu 12. 04 but I don't have Drivers for Ubuntu

[image].

When I press Call button nothing happened so I think that my problem is microphone recording problem. I have Compaq Presario CQ58 Series 100 and I cannot find drivers except the `.exe` for Windows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
sudo apt-get install libpulse0:i386
```

This looks like a frequent problem.

Comment: Also remember to reboot after running mentioned command